# Generic base class with multiple children

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I currently have a small object hierarchy that looks like this:

```
public class BaseClass {
    // this class is empty and exists only so the others can extend it and share the
    // same base type
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass {
    public Subject<AssociatedClassA> Results;
}

public class ChildB : BaseClass {
    public Subject<AssociatedClassB> Results;
}
```

In my design I would like to enforce that every class that extends from `BaseClass` should contain a `Subject<SomeType>` called `Results`. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can move Results into the base class or an interface such that I can supply the generic type for the `Subject` when constructing the base class. For example, it would be awesome if I could do something like this:

```
ChildA<AssociatedClassA> instance = new ChildA<AssociatedClassA>();
```

Or even better since there should really only be one template parameter that matches with ChildA if when I constructed it that could be taken care of for me:

```
ChildA instance = new ChildA();
// Results is automatically set to Subject<AssociatedClassA>
```

I'm stuck trying to implement this now as if I try to move Results into the base class the Subject requires a template parameter which I can't necessarily supply. There could potentially be more than 2 derived classes and I don't like the idea that someone extending this system has to know to add Results manually to each child class.

Following the suggestions of the 2 answers below this solves my desire to move Results into the base class, however I've run into another issue in that I was hoping to be able to use BaseClass as a generic parameter to methods such that any of the derived classes could be used. For example:

```
 public void ProcessBaseClass(BaseClass base) {
     // base could be ChildA or ChildB here
 }
```

This no longer works since `BaseClass` now requires a type argument. Is there any way that I can have the best of both worlds here or am I stuck due to my design choices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If appropriate, you can make the parent generic:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    public Subject<T> Results;
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass<AssociatedClassA> {
}

public class ChildB : BaseClass<AssociatedClassB> {
}
```

Comment: Any chance you might have some thoughts regarding the Edit I made to the original post?

Comment: @JesseCarter: Depending on the situation, you can make it `ProcessBaseClass<T>()` or make `BaseClass<T>` inherit from `BaseClass`. Or make an interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the base class itself generic:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    public T Results { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: @Jesse Further to this, if your `AssociatedClass` types are also in a type hierarchy, you can have a generic constraint on your base class: `BaseClass<T> where T : BaseAssociatedClass { }`, allowing for some base behaviour to show through.